# Webpack Unrecognized Input because of third party less file using \9

Tags: webpack, antd

So, I am using Ant Design systems Menu component ( I am using other components from them, and all is good ), but this Menu component uses some css that has a IE9 fallback, "\9".. and its killing my build process.

error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-3!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/lib/menu/style/index.css
Module build failed: 

  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) \9;
                                ^
Unrecognised input
      in /Users/dd/BRANCHES/sandbox/code/ui/node_modules/antd/lib/menu/style/index.css (line 244, column 34)
```

I am guessing this is a webpack issue, and this what I have:

```
{
        test: /\.(less|css)$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            { loader: 'css-loader' },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: function() {
                  return [autoprefixer];
                }
              }
            },
            { loader: 'less-loader' }
          ]
        })
```

I am using: "webpack": "^3.7.1", (( can't upgrade at this time )).

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You are using css-loader to handle less files, try `less-loader` in priority.

Comment: I did. I changed up the ordering and it didn't seem to matter :-( thanks though.